# Python : How to add for each element of a list every element from another list?

Tags: python, list, loops

I'm really new to Python and I would like to manage some lists that I created. So, in list A I have the last two digits of years and in list B I have numbers from 000 to 999.

For each year in list A, I want to add every number in list B I guess using a loop...

```
listA = ['00', '01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39', '40', '41', '42', '43', '44', '45', '46', '47', '48', '49', '50', '51', '52', '53', '54', '55', '56', '57', '58', '59', '60', '61', '62', '63', '64', '65', '66', '67', '68', '69', '70', '71', '72', '73', '74', '75', '76', '77', '78', '79', '80', '81', '82', '83', '84', '85', '86', '87', '88', '89', '90', '91', '92', '93', '94', '95', '96', '97', '98', '99']

listB = ['000', '001', '002', '003', ...]
```

*** somethingsomething loop ***

```
listC = ['00000', '00001', '00002', ...]
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to iterate over `listB`, so you would do:

```
for itemB in listB:
```

And then for each of these items, you will need to match it with every element in `listA`, so you would do another nested loop over `listA`.

```
for itemA in listA:
```

And then inside both loops, you would have all combinations of `itemA` and `itemB`. So you will just need to concatenate them and add them to an output list.

#### Full Solution

```
ouptut = []
for itemB in listB:
  for itemA in listA:
    output.append(itemB + itemA)
```

[`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) as mentioned in another solution, could give you a more concise solution, since it replaces the two `for` loops.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).

```
from itertools import product

listA = ['00', '01', '02', '03']
listB = ['000', '001', '002', '003']

listC = [a + b for a, b in product(listB, listA)] # ['00000', '00001', '00002', ...]
```

The `product` function iterates through the Cartesian product of the supplied iterables (the k-tuples of all combinations drawing one from each list). String concatenation is used to join the elements of the tuple (`a + b`). The list comprehension puts them all into a big ol' list.

Answer (score 1):

While [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) is handy, a simple nested comprehension will do just as fine:

```
list_a = ['00', '01', '02', '03']  # Python conventions call for snake_case
list_b = ['000', '001', '002', '003']

list_c = [b + a for b in list_b for a in list_a]
# ['00000', '00001', '00002', '00003', ... ]
```

Note here that the *first* `for` has the *wider* scope, which sometimes seems counter-intuitive compared to natural English.

Answer (score 0):

```py
> Code to reproduce listA

listA = []
for i in range(0,10):
    for j in range(0,10):
        e = str(i)+str(j)
        listA.append(e)
print(listA)

> Code to reproduce listB


listB = []
for i in range(0,10):
    for j in range(0,10):
        for k in range(0,10):
            e = str(i)+str(j)+str(k)
            listB.append(e)
print(listB)

> Now we just iterate over each element of listA and append one by one each element of listB, and keep appending the result to listC to get the final output list



listC = []
for i in listA:
    for j in listB:

        listC.append(i+j)
print(listC)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it works better than what the OP provided.

Answer (score -4):

You can use the inbuild function zip()

For example:

```
class SumList():

    def __init__(self, this_list):
        self.mylist = this_list

    def __add__(self, other):
        new_list = [ x + y for x,y in zip(self.mylist, other.mylist)]
        return SumList(new_list)

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.mylist)

cc = SumList([1,2,3,4])
dd = SumList([100,200,300,400])    
ee = cc + dd
print(ee)
```

Comment: This isn't what OP wants (made pretty clear by the fact that two lists have unequal lengths).

Comment: Why in the world would you wrap this in a class?